# What am I doing wrong calculating natural logarithm of this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, logarithms

> $$
> A=\begin{bmatrix}     4 & -15 & 6 \\   1 & -4 &2 \\ 1 & -5 &3   \end{bmatrix} 
> $$
>   Find natural logarithm of $A$.

I notice $Sp_A=\{1,1,1\}$. So $(A-E)^3$ must be zero.

$\ln(E+(A-E))=(A-E)-\frac{(A-E)^2}{2}$

Calculating, I get just a regular matrix with integers, but the key in the book says

$$\begin{bmatrix}     3 & -15 & 6 \\   1 & -5 &2 \\ 1 & -5 &2   \end{bmatrix} + 2\pi in E, n\in \mathbb{Z}.$$

**Where do $\pi$ and $i$ come from?**

Comment: Is $E$ the identity matrix?

Comment: Can you clarify the notation? What are Spa and E?

Comment: @Arthur Yes, it is.

Comment: @Arun Matrix spectrum and identity matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first look at $1\times 1$ matrices instead. Those are some times more intuitive. For instance, the natural logarithm of the matrix $[e]$ is $[1]+2\pi i n[1]$ because $e^{1+2\pi in}=1$ for any integer $n$.

In your case it's exactly the same thing happening, only your matrices are $3\times 3$.

Answer (score 0):

The principal $\log$ of $A$ is $A-I_3$. Yet, there are many other logarithms of $A$.

$A$ is similar to $B=diag(I_2+J_2,1)$ where $J_k$ is the nilpotent Jordan block of dimension $k$. Then the $\log$'s of $B$ may have two types

Type 1. Primary functions (cf. Higham, Functions of matrices); they are polynomials in $B$.

$B-I_3+2i\pi k I_3$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Type 2. Non-primary functions; they are not polynomials in $B$.

EDIT. $Udiag(J_2+2i\pi lI_2,2i\pi k)U^{-1}$ where $UB=BU$ and $k,l\in \mathbb{Z}$.